.jar file opens only if I run it from the cmd console, but not if I double-click it
I've build a Java program (.jar) using maven, but it opens only by java -jar kalkulator-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar and I want it to open by just double-clicking it.  
I'm using Win10, java version 21.0.5, Apache Maven 3.9.9  
I've reinstalled Java, checked if other versions are installed on my PC, checked JAVA_HOME setup and PATH to jdk-21/bin, tried opening it by java.exe and javaw.exe, there's no MANIFEST file in the project for now, but I've opened built .jar app in winrar and added Main-Class: com.Kalkulator.Main to MAINFEST there.  
I've built it in intelliJ (2023.3.2) console by:
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn test
mvn package
mvn install

I've also implemented maven-assembly-plugin whitch is included in the pom.xml file, I'm adding:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Kalkulator</groupId>
    <artifactId>kalkulator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    
</project>

Project structure:  
Project_1  
├───.idea
├───.mvn
│   └───wrapper
├───out
│   └───artifacts
│       └───Project_1_jar
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───Kalkulator
│   └───test
│       └───java
└───target
├---.gitignore  
├---mvnw  
├---mvnw.cmd  
├---pom.xml  
├---Project_1.iml  
In src/main/java/com/Kalkulator there are two Java Classes named Main and Project.

You can set the Main-Class using the <archive><manifest><mainClass> configuration setting of the Maven JAR plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

Unfortunately, that's still not it @RobSpoor

On Windows 10, in order to run a file by double-clicking it in File Explorer, there has to be a file association for it. I'm guessing that you don't have a file association for .jar files. Do you get an error message when you double-click the JAR file?

@Abra Not now. Previously, I had an error ,,Java exception occurred" but now for a split second small cmd look alike window pops out and closes immediately

That window probably displays an error that you can't see since it disappears quickly. I don't know how you can stop that window from disappearing. But did you check the file associations?

I did the '''ftype jarfile" (responce: jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*) and than ,,assoc .jar" (resp: .jar=jarfile) but it's still not working @Abra
When I'm trying to open it through cmd now, I'm also getting the ,,no main manifest attribute" error in one file, and ,,Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fully.qualified.MainClass" in the other. I didn't happened 'till I did the  from the previous suggestion
